# How can I set the amount of hours that are displayed on a calendar widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the package calendar_view. It displays all the hours of the day in any view(day,week,month). Is there a way to limit this view? EX The hour range 7:00 am - 4:00 PM to only be displayed.

I cant seem to find the right parameter on their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DayView widget, it shows the hours of the current day,

You can look this calendar_day_view: ^3.1.1